# android - add Fragment in containerViewId to Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm faced with following problem:

`MainActivity` is mainly a `ViewPager` where I can slide through cards (`Fragment`). This cards have a placeholder `ViewGroup` where another content (`Fragment`) is placed in during runtime. The problem is that the content is placed only in one card.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extend FragmentActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // ...
        // init ViewPager
        getViewPager().setAdapter(new CardSelectionAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    // ...

    private class CardSelectionAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        // ...

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new CardFragment(someData);
        }
    }
}
```

**CardFragment**

```
public class CardFragment extends Fragment {

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card, container, false);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.actionSheet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void populate() {
        // ...

        Fragment f;
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_A: f = new ActionsAFragment(); break;
            case TYPE_B: f = new ActionsBFragment(); break;
            default: f = null;
        }

        if (f != null) {
            // Here should be the main problem when adding Fragment to container/placeholder
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.actionSheet, f).commit();
            getView().findViewById(R.id.actionSheet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
}
```

I think because all cards belong to `MainActivity`, `FragmentTransaction` can only add to one `ViewGroup` with `id R.id.actionSheet`.

Is there another way how I can add content to layout with same ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are calling `populate`. You should change `populate` to accept the parent view (instead of adding the fragment to R.id.actionsheet every time) and call it from `onCreateView` and pass it the view you just created. That way you don't have a problem with multiple views inside actionSheet with the same ID. However there is so much code missing I can't be exactly sure what to do here.

By the way, when you are dealing with nested fragments - inside of `populate`, you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()` solved my problem. Thanks! BTW `populate()` is called by a `BroadCastReceiver` when some data is received. Sorry for this leak of information.